# magento 1.8.1.0 to magento 2.2.2 migrate data issue

Tags: magento2.2.2, data-migration-tool

**- magento 1.8.1.0 to magento 2.2.2 migrate data this types of issue are face**

```
    ,5029,5033,5037,5038,5041,5051,5062,5067,5068,5071,5072,5073,5085,5086,5087,5088
,5090 from `sales_flat_order_item`.`order_id` has no referenced records in `sale
s_flat_order`←[0m
←[0;33m[2018-04-20 12:18:25][WARNING]: Foreign key (FK_SALES_FLAT_ORDER_PAYMENT_
PARENT_ID_SALES_FLAT_ORDER_ENTITY_ID) constraint fails on source database. Orpha
n records id: 5,8,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31,32,33,34
,35,36,37,38,39,40,41,43,44,46,47,48,49,50,51,52,53,54,55,56,57,58,59,60,61,62,6
,4748,4750,4751,4756,4769,4772,4780,4781,4785,4786,4792,4793,4794,4802,4805,5090 from `sales_flat_or
der_status_history`.`parent_id` has no referenced records in `sales_flat_order`←
[0m
←[0;33m[2018-04-20 12:18:25][WARNING]: Foreign key (FK_SALESRULE_COUPON_RULE_ID_
SALESRULE_RULE_ID) constraint fails on source database. Orphan records id: 9 fro
m `salesrule_coupon`.`rule_id` has no referenced records in `salesrule`←[0m
←[0;33m[2018-04-20 12:18:25][WARNING]: Foreign key (FK_SALESRULE_CUSTOMER_GROUP_
RULE_ID_SALESRULE_RULE_ID) constraint fails on source database. Orphan records i
d: 9 from `salesrule_customer_group`.`rule_id` has no referenced records in `sal
esrule`←[0m
←[0;33m[2018-04-20 12:18:25][WARNING]: Foreign key (FK_SALESRULE_WEBSITE_RULE_ID
_SALESRULE_RULE_ID) constraint fails on source database. Orphan records id: 9 fr
om `salesrule_website`.`rule_id` has no referenced records in `salesrule`←[0m
←[0;33m[2018-04-20 12:18:25][WARNING]: Foreign key (FK_TAG_FIRST_CUSTOMER_ID_CUS
TOMER_ENTITY_ENTITY_ID) constraint fails on source database. Orphan records id:
0 from `tag`.`first_customer_id` has no referenced records in `customer_entity`←
[0m
←[0;33m[2018-04-20 12:18:25][WARNING]: Foreign key (FK_TAX_CALCULATION_CUSTOMER_
TAX_CLASS_ID_TAX_CLASS_CLASS_ID) constraint fails on source database. Orphan rec
ords id: 3 from `tax_calculation`.`customer_tax_class_id` has no referenced reco
rds in `tax_class`←[0m
←[0;33m[2018-04-20 12:18:25][WARNING]: Foreign key (FK_TAX_CALCULATION_PRODUCT_T
AX_CLASS_ID_TAX_CLASS_CLASS_ID) constraint fails on source database. Orphan reco
rds id: 5,6,7 from `tax_calculation`.`product_tax_class_id` has no referenced re
cords in `tax_class`←[0m
←[0;33m[2018-04-20 12:18:25][WARNING]: Foreign key (FK_TAX_CALC_TAX_CALC_RATE_ID
_TAX_CALC_RATE_TAX_CALC_RATE_ID) constraint fails on source database. Orphan rec
ords id: 3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,
29,30,31,32,33,34,35,36,37,38,39,40,41,42,43,44,45,46,47,48,49 from `tax_calcula
tion`.`tax_calculation_rate_id` has no referenced records in `tax_calculation_ra
te`←[0m
←[0;33m[2018-04-20 12:18:25][WARNING]: Foreign key (FK_TAX_CALC_TAX_CALC_RULE_ID
_TAX_CALC_RULE_TAX_CALC_RULE_ID) constraint fails on source database. Orphan rec
ords id: 2,3,4 from `tax_calculation`.`tax_calculation_rule_id` has no reference
d records in `tax_calculation_rule`←[0m
[2018-04-20 12:18:25][INFO][mode: data][stage: integrity check][step: EAV Step]:
 started
←[2K100% [============================] Remaining Time: < 1 sec
[2018-04-20 12:18:25][INFO][mode: data][stage: integrity check][step: Customer A
ttributes Step]: started
←[2K100% [============================] Remaining Time: < 1 sec
[2018-04-20 12:18:25][INFO][mode: data][stage: integrity check][step: Map Step]:
 started
←[2K100% [============================] Remaining Time: < 1 sec
[2018-04-20 12:18:28][INFO][mode: data][stage: integrity check][step: Url Rewrit
e Step]: started
←[2K100% [============================] Remaining Time: < 1 sec
[2018-04-20 12:18:28][INFO][mode: data][stage: integrity check][step: Log Step]:
 started
←[2K100% [============================] Remaining Time: < 1 sec
[2018-04-20 12:18:28][INFO][mode: data][stage: integrity check][step: Ratings St
ep]: started
←[2K100% [============================] Remaining Time: < 1 sec
[2018-04-20 12:18:28][INFO][mode: data][stage: integrity check][step: Configurab
lePrices step]: started
←[2K100% [============================] Remaining Time: < 1 sec
[2018-04-20 12:18:28][INFO][mode: data][stage: integrity check][step: OrderGrids
 Step]: started
←[2K100% [============================] Remaining Time: < 1 sec
[2018-04-20 12:18:28][INFO][mode: data][stage: integrity check][step: Tier Price
 Step]: started
←[2K100% [============================] Remaining Time: < 1 sec
[2018-04-20 12:18:28][INFO][mode: data][stage: integrity check][step: SalesIncre
ment Step]: started
←[2K100% [============================] Remaining Time: < 1 sec
[2018-04-20 12:18:28][INFO][mode: data][stage: setup triggers][step: Stage]: sta
rted
←[2K100% [============================] Remaining Time: < 1 sec
[2018-04-20 12:18:38][INFO][mode: data][stage: data migration][step: EAV Step]:
started
←[2K28% [========>-------------------] Remaining Time: < 1 sec

  [PDOException]  SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '0' f  or key 'PRIMARY'


migrate:data [-r|--reset] [-a|--auto] [--] <config>
```

Comment: https://community.magento.com/t5/Installing-Magento-2-x/data-migration-tool-map-xml/td-p/23244

Comment: https://github.com/magento-panda/data-migration-tool/commit/e69cefdefbf379bb0f380440024965ce8cd7d530

Comment: https://web4pro.net/blog-news/migration-magento-2-using-magento-2-data-migration-tool/

Answer (score 0):

C:/wamp64/www/test/vendor/magento/data-migration-tool/etc/opensource-to-opensource/1.8.1.0/config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!--
/**
 * Copyright © 2013-2017 Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
-->
<config xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xs:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../config.xsd">
    <steps mode="settings">
        <step title="Settings Step">
            <integrity>Migration\Step\Settings\Integrity</integrity>
            <data>Migration\Step\Settings\Data</data>
        </step>
        <step title="Stores Step">
            <integrity>Migration\Step\Stores\Integrity</integrity>
            <data>Migration\Step\Stores\Data</data>
            <volume>Migration\Step\Stores\Volume</volume>
        </step>
    </steps>
    <steps mode="data">
        <step title="Data Integrity Step">
            <integrity>Migration\Step\DataIntegrity\Integrity</integrity>
        </step>
        <step title="EAV Step">
            <integrity>Migration\Step\Eav\Integrity</integrity>
            <data>Migration\Step\Eav\Data</data>
            <volume>Migration\Step\Eav\Volume</volume>
        </step>
        <step title="Customer Attributes Step">
            <integrity>Migration\Step\Customer\Integrity</integrity>
            <data>Migration\Step\Customer\Data</data>
            <volume>Migration\Step\Customer\Volume</volume>
        </step>
        <step title="Map Step">
            <integrity>Migration\Step\Map\Integrity</integrity>
            <data>Migration\Step\Map\Data</data>
            <volume>Migration\Step\Map\Volume</volume>
        </step>
        <step title="Url Rewrite Step">
            <integrity>Migration\Step\UrlRewrite\Version191to2000</integrity>
            <data>Migration\Step\UrlRewrite\Version191to2000</data>
            <volume>Migration\Step\UrlRewrite\Version191to2000</volume>
        </step>
        <step title="Log Step">
            <integrity>Migration\Step\Log\Integrity</integrity>
            <data>Migration\Step\Log\Data</data>
            <volume>Migration\Step\Log\Volume</volume>
        </step>
        <step title="Ratings Step">
            <integrity>Migration\Step\Ratings\Integrity</integrity>
            <data>Migration\Step\Ratings\Data</data>
            <volume>Migration\Step\Ratings\Volume</volume>
        </step>
        <step title="ConfigurablePrices step">
            <integrity>Migration\Step\ConfigurablePrices\Integrity</integrity>
            <data>Migration\Step\ConfigurablePrices\Data</data>
            <volume>Migration\Step\ConfigurablePrices\Volume</volume>
        </step>
        <step title="OrderGrids Step">
            <integrity>Migration\Step\OrderGrids\Integrity</integrity>
            <data>Migration\Step\OrderGrids\Data</data>
            <volume>Migration\Step\OrderGrids\Volume</volume>
        </step>
        <step title="Tier Price Step">
            <integrity>Migration\Step\TierPrice\Integrity</integrity>
            <data>Migration\Step\TierPrice\Data</data>
            <volume>Migration\Step\TierPrice\Volume</volume>
        </step>
        <step title="SalesIncrement Step">
            <integrity>Migration\Step\SalesIncrement\Integrity</integrity>
            <data>Migration\Step\SalesIncrement\Data</data>
            <volume>Migration\Step\SalesIncrement\Volume</volume>
        </step>
        <step title="PostProcessing Step">
            <data>Migration\Step\PostProcessing\Data</data>
        </step>
    </steps>
    <steps mode="delta">
        <step title="Customer Attributes Step">
            <delta>Migration\Step\Customer\Delta</delta>
            <volume>Migration\Step\Customer\Volume</volume>
        </step>
        <step title="Map Step">
            <delta>Migration\Step\Map\Delta</delta>
            <volume>Migration\Step\Map\Volume</volume>
        </step>
        <step title="Log Step">
            <delta>Migration\Step\Log\Delta</delta>
            <volume>Migration\Step\Log\Volume</volume>
        </step>
        <step title="OrderGrids Step">
            <delta>Migration\Step\OrderGrids\Delta</delta>
            <volume>Migration\Step\OrderGrids\Volume</volume>
        </step>
        <step title="SalesIncrement Step">
            <delta>Migration\Step\SalesIncrement\Delta</delta>
            <volume>Migration\Step\SalesIncrement\Volume</volume>
        </step>
    </steps>
    <source>
        <database host="localhost" name="test" user="root"/>
    </source>
    <destination>
        <database host="localhost" name="magento222_migrate" user="root"/>
    </destination>
    <options>
        <map_file>etc/opensource-to-opensource/1.8.1.0/map.xml</map_file>
        <eav_map_file>etc/opensource-to-opensource/1.8.1.0/map-eav.xml</eav_map_file>
        <eav_document_groups_file>etc/opensource-to-opensource/1.8.1.0/eav-document-groups.xml</eav_document_groups_file>
        <eav_attribute_groups_file>etc/opensource-to-opensource/1.8.1.0/eav-attribute-groups.xml</eav_attribute_groups_file>
        <log_map_file>etc/opensource-to-opensource/1.8.1.0/map-log.xml</log_map_file>
        <log_document_groups_file>etc/opensource-to-opensource/1.8.1.0/log-document-groups.xml</log_document_groups_file>
        <settings_map_file>etc/opensource-to-opensource/1.8.1.0/settings.xml</settings_map_file>
        <customer_map_file>etc/opensource-to-opensource/1.8.1.0/map-customer.xml</customer_map_file>
        <customer_document_groups_file>etc/opensource-to-opensource/1.8.1.0/customer-document-groups.xml</customer_document_groups_file>
        <customer_attribute_groups_file>etc/opensource-to-opensource/1.8.1.0/customer-attribute-groups.xml</customer_attribute_groups_file>
        <delta_document_groups_file>etc/opensource-to-opensource/1.8.1.0/deltalog.xml</delta_document_groups_file>
        <order_grids_document_groups_file>etc/opensource-to-opensource/1.8.1.0/order-grids-document-groups.xml</order_grids_document_groups_file>
        <map_document_groups>etc/opensource-to-opensource/1.8.1.0/map-document-groups.xml</map_document_groups>
        <class_map>etc/opensource-to-opensource/1.8.1.0/class-map.xml</class_map>
        <tier_price_map_file>etc/opensource-to-opensource/1.8.1.0/map-tier-price.xml</tier_price_map_file>
        <stores_map_file>etc/opensource-to-opensource/1.8.1.0/map-stores.xml</stores_map_file>
        <!--
        In case bulk_size=0 it will be auto-detected for every document.
        -->
        <bulk_size>0</bulk_size>
        <!--
        Set direct_document_copy = 1 for better performance.
        NOTE: 'source' and 'destination' databases MUST be placed on the same MySQL instance
        and 'destination' user MUST be granted with 'SELECT' permissions on 'source' database
         -->
        <direct_document_copy>0</direct_document_copy>
        <source_prefix />
        <dest_prefix />
        <auto_resolve_urlrewrite_duplicates>0</auto_resolve_urlrewrite_duplicates>
        <log_file>migration.log</log_file>
        <progress_bar_format>%percent%% [%bar%] Remaining Time: %remaining%</progress_bar_format>
        <upgrade_customer_password_hash>1</upgrade_customer_password_hash>
        <edition_migrate>opensource-to-opensource</edition_migrate>
        <edition_number>1.8.1.0</edition_number>
        <init_statements_source>SET NAMES utf8;</init_statements_source>
        <init_statements_destination>SET NAMES utf8;</init_statements_destination>
        <crypt_key>2c5f027b165e187c6b72d92c2bfa2ccd</crypt_key>
    </options>
</config>
```

C:/wamp64/www/test/vendor/magento/data-migration-tool/etc/opensource-to-opensource/1.8.1.0/map.xml

```
  <!--custom ignored documents -->
            <ignore>
                <document>aw_blog</document>
            </ignore>
            <ignore>
                <document>aw_blog_cat</document>
            </ignore>
            <ignore>
                <document>aw_blog_cat_store</document>
            </ignore>
            <ignore>
                <document>aw_blog_comment</document>
            </ignore>
            <ignore>
                <document>aw_blog_post_cat</document>
            </ignore>
            <ignore>
                <document>aw_blog_store</document>
            </ignore>
            <ignore>
                <document>aw_blog_tags</document>
            </ignore>
            <ignore>
                <document>ebizmarts_autoresponder_backtostock</document>
            </ignore>
            <ignore>
                <document>ebizmarts_autoresponder_backtostock_alert</document>
            </ignore>
            <ignore>
                <document>ebizmarts_autoresponder_review</document>
            </ignore>
            <ignore>
                <document>ebizmarts_autoresponder_unsubscribe</document>
            </ignore>
            <ignore>
                <document>ebizmarts_autoresponder_visited</document>
            </ignore>
            <ignore>
                <document>find_feed_import_codes</document>
            </ignore>
            <ignore>
                <document>googlecheckout_notification</document>
            </ignore>
            <ignore>
                <document>magemonkey_api_debug</document>
            </ignore>
            <ignore>
                <document>magemonkey_async_orders</document>
            </ignore>
            <ignore>
                <document>magemonkey_async_subscribers</document>
            </ignore>
            <ignore>
                <document>magemonkey_bulksync_export</document>
            </ignore>
            <ignore>
                <document>magemonkey_bulksync_import</document>
            </ignore>
            <ignore>
                <document>magemonkey_ecommerce360</document>
            </ignore>
            <ignore>
                <document>magemonkey_mails_sent</document>
            </ignore>
            <ignore>
                <document>payplug_payments_card</document>
            </ignore>
            <ignore>
                <document>payplug_payments_order_payment</document>
            </ignore>
            <ignore>
                <document>payplug_payments_quote_payment</document>
            </ignore>
            <ignore>
                <document>email_automation</document>
            </ignore>
            <ignore>
                <document>email_campaign</document>
            </ignore>
            <ignore>
                <document>email_catalog</document>
            </ignore>
            <ignore>
                <document>email_contact</document>
            </ignore>
            <ignore>
                <document>email_importer</document>
            </ignore>
            <ignore>
                <document>email_order</document>
            </ignore>
            <ignore>
                <document>email_review</document>
            </ignore>
            <ignore>
                <document>email_rules</document>
            </ignore>
            <ignore>
                <document>email_wishlist</document>
            </ignore>
            <ignore>
                <document>temando_checkout_address</document>
            </ignore>
            <ignore>
                <document>temando_order</document>
            </ignore>
            <ignore>
                <document>temando_shipment</document>
            </ignore>
            <!--End custom ignored documents -->


<!--Here are my custom ignored fields-->
            <ignore>
                <field>sales_flat_order.ebizmarts_abandonedcart_flag</field>
            </ignore>
            <ignore>
                <field>sales_flat_order.ebizmarts_magemonkey_campaign_id</field>
            </ignore>
            <ignore>
                <field>sales_flat_quote.ebizmarts_abandonedcart_counter</field>
            </ignore>
            <ignore>
                <field>sales_flat_quote.ebizmarts_abandonedcart_flag</field>
            </ignore>
            <ignore>
                <field>sales_flat_quote.ebizmarts_abandonedcart_token</field>
            </ignore>
            <!--End of custom ignored fields-->
```